# Got an error in .NET MVC 4 app with MYSQL: System.DllNotFoundException: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to launch **.Net MVC4** framework app on server and got the error below.
I have **external MYSQL Server** and it works well with the same application on my local computer. But when I launch it on server, I get this error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity, Version=6.9.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d**

**Description:**

> An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

**Exception Details:**

> System.DllNotFoundException: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity, Version=6.9.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d

**Source Error:**

```
Line 1230:              modelQuery = modelQuery.Where(i => i.amsu_status_admin == "active");
Line 1231:
Line 1232:          if (!modelQuery.Any()) return new MapFilterModel();
Line 1233:
Line 1234:          var model = modelQuery.OrderBy(i => i.amsu_status_admin)
```

**Stack Trace:**

```
[DllNotFoundException: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity, Version=6.9.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d]
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory.get_MySqlDbProviderServicesInstance() +343
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory.System.IServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType) +112
   System.Data.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderServices(DbProviderFactory factory) +135
   System.Data.Metadata.Edm.Loader.InitializeProviderManifest(Action`3 addError) +119
   System.Data.Metadata.Edm.Loader.OnProviderManifestTokenNotification(String token, Action`3 addError) +36
   System.Data.EntityModel.SchemaObjectModel.Schema.HandleProviderManifestTokenAttribute(XmlReader reader) +97
   System.Data.EntityModel.SchemaObjectModel.Schema.HandleAttribute(XmlReader reader) +363
   System.Data.EntityModel.SchemaObjectModel.SchemaElement.ParseAttribute(XmlReader reader) +100
   System.Data.EntityModel.SchemaObjectModel.SchemaElement.Parse(XmlReader reader) +75
   System.Data.EntityModel.SchemaObjectModel.Schema.HandleTopLevelSchemaElement(XmlReader reader) +36
   System.Data.EntityModel.SchemaObjectModel.Schema.InternalParse(XmlReader sourceReader, String sourceLocation) +751
   System.Data.EntityModel.SchemaObjectModel.Schema.Parse(XmlReader sourceReader, String sourceLocation) +56
   System.Data.EntityModel.SchemaObjectModel.SchemaManager.ParseAndValidate(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders, IEnumerable`1 sourceFilePaths, SchemaDataModelOption dataModel, AttributeValueNotification providerNotification, AttributeValueNotification providerManifestTokenNotification, ProviderManifestNeeded providerManifestNeeded, IList`1& schemaCollection) +389
   System.Data.Metadata.Edm.Loader.LoadItems(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders, IEnumerable`1 sourceFilePaths) +158
   System.Data.Metadata.Edm.StoreItemCollection.Init(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders, IEnumerable`1 filePaths, Boolean throwOnError, DbProviderManifest& providerManifest, DbProviderFactory& providerFactory, String& providerManifestToken, Memoizer`2& cachedCTypeFunction) +177
   System.Data.Metadata.Edm.StoreItemCollection..ctor(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders, IEnumerable`1 filePaths) +238
   System.Data.Metadata.Edm.StoreMetadataEntry.LoadStoreCollection(EdmItemCollection edmItemCollection, MetadataArtifactLoader loader) +90
   System.Data.Metadata.Edm.StoreItemCollectionLoader.LoadItemCollection(StoreMetadataEntry entry) +20
   System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataCache.LoadItemCollection(IItemCollectionLoader`1 itemCollectionLoader, T entry) +127
   System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataCache.GetOrCreateStoreAndMappingItemCollections(String cacheKey, MetadataArtifactLoader loader, EdmItemCollection edmItemCollection, Object& entryToken) +191
   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.LoadStoreItemCollections(MetadataWorkspace workspace, DbConnection storeConnection, DbProviderFactory factory, DbConnectionOptions connectionOptions, EdmItemCollection edmItemCollection, MetadataArtifactLoader artifactLoader) +258
   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.GetMetadataWorkspace(Boolean initializeAllCollections) +574
   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.InitializeMetadata(DbConnection newConnection, DbConnection originalConnection, Boolean closeOriginalConnectionOnFailure) +75
   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open() +150
   System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection() +75
   System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption) +40
   System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator() +31
   System.Linq.Enumerable.Single(IEnumerable`1 source) +101
   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.<>c__11`1.<GetElementFunction>b__11_3(IEnumerable`1 sequence) +7
   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.ExecuteSingle(IEnumerable`1 query, Expression queryRoot) +25
   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression) +70
   System.Linq.Queryable.Any(IQueryable`1 source) +196
   Realbc.Controllers.HomeController.GetMapFilterModelByObjectIds(IQueryable`1 objectsIds, Int32 skipForMax) in c:\inetpub\sites\Realbc\source\Realbc\Realbc\Controllers\HomeController.cs:1232
   Realbc.Controllers.HomeController.Index() in c:\inetpub\sites\Realbc\source\Realbc\Realbc\Controllers\HomeController.cs:43
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +102
   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +435
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +60
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.ActionInvocation.InvokeSynchronousActionMethod() +76
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +36
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +73
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +136
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +102
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d() +117
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +323
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass33.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +44
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +47
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +136
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +102
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() +72
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +185
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +133
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +56
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +70
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +133
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +56
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +37
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +44
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +62
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +133
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +56
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +37
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +70
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +133
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +56
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +37
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40 System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +38
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9744261
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found the answer. The problem was in different version mysql connector and nugetPackage for mysql connector.
(I've installed mysql connector 6.9.9, but nugetPackage was for mysql connector 6.9.8)

So you need install **exactly the same version of mysql-connector and nugetPackage** for connector to make it works.